# Please explain below how these commands work to fetch two URLs?

Tags: command-line-interface, jq

`watch -n2 "curl -s https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=hyderabad | jq -r '.[] | .woeid' |  xargs -I% curl -s https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/%/ | jq '.consolidated_weather[0].wind_speed,.consolidated_weather[0].the_temp'"`

It is the url for fetching location temperature and wind from two URLs. I do not understand how they fetched it. Please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

curl is a command used to communicate with the server. Your first URL is an API endpoint for the metaweather location search API. "?query=hyderabad" tells the server to get the data for "hyderabad". The server responds with:

```
[{"title":"Hyderabad","location_type":"City","woeid":2295414,"latt_long":"17.508829,78.434578"}]
```

the "woeid" parameter represents the ID of your location. The command then takes that woeid and sends it to the other API endpoint. The second API takes that woeid, uses it to find your location, and responds with the following info:

```
{"consolidated_weather":[{"id":4943876231004160,"weather_state_name":"Showers","weather_state_abbr":"s","wind_direction_compass":"SSE","created":"2022-01-10T04:50:35.034292Z","applicable_date":"2022-01-10","min_temp":19.145,"max_temp":27.775,"the_temp":25.700000000000003,"wind_speed":4.491323107826295,"wind_direction":154.44033101452658,"air_pressure":1015.0,"humidity":70,"visibility":9.777586395450568,"predictability":73},{"id":6357293160464384,"weather_state_name":"Light Rain","weather_state_abbr":"lr","wind_direction_compass":"SSE","created":"2022-01-10T04:50:38.005159Z","applicable_date":"2022-01-11","min_temp":18.205,"max_temp":28.07,"the_temp":25.89,"wind_speed":6.292207290389459,"wind_direction":154.50026675861483,"air_pressure":1014.5,"humidity":67,"visibility":11.256760518571543,"predictability":75},{"id":4953107759890432,"weather_state_name":"Showers","weather_state_abbr":"s","wind_direction_compass":"SSE","created":"2022-01-10T04:50:41.160848Z","applicable_date":"2022-01-12","min_temp":18.115,"max_temp":29.41,"the_temp":26.65,"wind_speed":5.614736243593415,"wind_direction":163.24826086181199,"air_pressure":1013.5,"humidity":63,"visibility":10.892015628728227,"predictability":73},{"id":4781031103135744,"weather_state_name":"Light Rain","weather_state_abbr":"lr","wind_direction_compass":"SSE","created":"2022-01-10T04:50:44.066091Z","applicable_date":"2022-01-13","min_temp":18.725,"max_temp":28.77,"the_temp":25.63,"wind_speed":6.143865224862801,"wind_direction":150.42762877821613,"air_pressure":1013.0,"humidity":65,"visibility":10.398646902091784,"predictability":75},{"id":4949918276911104,"weather_state_name":"Showers","weather_state_abbr":"s","wind_direction_compass":"SSW","created":"2022-01-10T04:50:47.040253Z","applicable_date":"2022-01-14","min_temp":19.295,"max_temp":28.17,"the_temp":25.805,"wind_speed":5.159495540358971,"wind_direction":203.78057282014655,"air_pressure":1013.5,"humidity":54,"visibility":10.962541259047164,"predictability":73},{"id":4891149274710016,"weather_state_name":"Showers","weather_state_abbr":"s","wind_direction_compass":"ESE","created":"2022-01-10T04:50:50.555320Z","applicable_date":"2022-01-15","min_temp":19.435,"max_temp":27.655,"the_temp":27.33,"wind_speed":5.123282828282829,"wind_direction":114.5,"air_pressure":1014.0,"humidity":55,"visibility":9.999726596675416,"predictability":73}],"time":"2022-01-10T11:04:08.669337+05:30","sun_rise":"2022-01-10T06:49:03.997088+05:30","sun_set":"2022-01-10T17:58:25.214998+05:30","timezone_name":"LMT","parent":{"title":"India","location_type":"Country","woeid":23424848,"latt_long":"21.786600,82.794762"},"sources":[{"title":"BBC","slug":"bbc","url":"http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/","crawl_rate":360},{"title":"Forecast.io","slug":"forecast-io","url":"http://forecast.io/","crawl_rate":480},{"title":"Met Office","slug":"met-office","url":"http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/","crawl_rate":180},{"title":"OpenWeatherMap","slug":"openweathermap","url":"http://openweathermap.org/","crawl_rate":360},{"title":"World Weather Online","slug":"world-weather-online","url":"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/","crawl_rate":360}],"title":"Hyderabad","location_type":"City","woeid":2295414,"latt_long":"17.508829,78.434578","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata"}
```

It then parses that response and fetches the wind speed and temperature from that data using this command:

```
jq '.consolidated_weather[0].wind_speed,.consolidated_weather[0].the_temp'"
```